# using GSMComm in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gsmcomm

I have developed a simple application (with VS2013) to send and received text messages via a GSM modem in C# using GSM Communication Library (GSMComm). Now, I want to use it on my “raspberry pi” with the help of mono. Everything is fine, but the big problem is, I have no idea what should I use instead of (in my case) COM3 to create a gsm connection (see the code below), as I know the name of my gsm-modem’s port in Linux is “ttyUSB0”.

```
GsmCommMain gsmPort = null;
…
gsmPort = new GsmCommMain(“COM3”, 9600 /*baudRate*/, 300 /*timeout*/);
```

Any idea?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `GSMPhone` class is using a std `SerialPort` class, so:

```
gsmPort = new GsmCommMain(“/dev/ttyUSB0”, 9600 /*baudRate*/, 300 /*timeout*/);
```

Ref: https://github.com/welly87/GSMComm/blob/e49cd0d803afd9b3b53df178404981b12ab81f23/GSMCommunication/GsmCommunication/GsmPhone.cs#L154

Ref: (old, but still valid reference) : http://www.mono-project.com/archived/howtosystemioports/

1) Assuming you have gsm-utils installed (

`apt-get install gsm-utils`

2) Assuming you have the proper perms to access:

`sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`

3) Assuming you can connect to that dev via a serial program, something like:

`moserial`, `zterm`, etc...

4) Try using `statserial` to verify that dev device:

`statserial /dev/ttyUSB0`

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your solution before but I got this error: "Unable to open port /dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid Serial Port"!  :-(

Comment: Thanks again. I did all the stuff and get: "Unable to open port /dev/ttyUSB0: Invalid Serial Port".  Any idea?

Comment: I would try skipping gsmcomm and write a simple serialport console app in c# and check the exception being thrown on the open call

Comment: Thanks again. Using gammu, I could send a text message: echo "text message" | sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "cellno". However, not successful to use gsmComm library :-/

Comment: @NacerFarajzadeh Using `sudo`? Are you running your c# console app as `sudo` also? Check the perms on `/dev/ttyUSB0`, blow them open as `777` as a test...